Hodge star decomposition in non-diagonal manifold product
I'm studying differential forms and I came across the following problem. From what I learnt in another question, when a manifold can be decomposed as $X \times Y$, then the formula found there works and I'm happy with it. 
Let's now say that, for clarity, instead of working with a simple factorization as $X \times Y$, we work with a metric of the form $ds_X^2 = dr^2 + r^2 ds_Y^2$, where now $X \sim \mathbb{R} \times Y$. 
Taking $\alpha \in \Omega^i(\mathbb{R})$ and $\beta \in \Omega^j(Y)$, what's the correct factorization of $\star_{X} (\alpha \wedge \beta)$ in terms of $\star_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\star_Y$?
I really have no clue, so I apologize if I can't really make any more assertion about the problem. I'd be happy just to be given a (correct) reference and work on it by myself, but if someone already knows the answer, that's be great.
Thanks everyone.

The best thing to do is to write down an orthonormal coframe. If $\theta_j$, $j=2,\dots,n$, are an orthonormal coframe for $ds_Y^2$, then you will have $$\omega_1=dr, \omega_2=r\theta_2,\dots \omega_n=r\theta_n.$$ Once you have an orthonormal coframe, it is easy to write down $\star$.

What you have here is a warped product, i.e a product manifold $M=B\times F$ a positive function $f:B\to\Bbb{R}$ and metric of the form $g=g_B+f^2g_F^2$ (or more precisely, $g=\pi_B^*g_B+(f\circ\pi_B)^2\pi_F^*g_F$). The best method for analyzing almost anything pertaining to warped products (connection, curvatures, Hodge stars etc) is by writing down an orthonormal coframe as suggested above. There are three main types of forms on the product (namely those purely from $B$, those purely from $F$, and the mixed ones like you’re asking about) and for all of these, the ON frame works wonders.

or… you could go back to your link and redo the derivation, just keeping in mind where pure orthogonality of the factors is used and where ‘normalization’ (i.e $f\equiv 1$, which is the case of a product Riemannian manifold) is used. And as a rough hint: my quick calculation tells me for $\dim B=n,\dim F=m$ and $k$-form $\beta$ on $B$, $l$-form $\phi$ on $F$, $\star(\beta\wedge \phi)=(-1)^{l(n-k)}f^{m-2l}(\star\beta)\wedge(\star\phi)$.

Thank you all for your answers.
@peek-a-boo , I tried to re-do the derivation and I kind of see where your result comes from, even though I guess I am still a bit confused in this step (which I think is the most relevant one):
$ \langle \mu \wedge \beta, \nu \wedge \phi\rangle \text{vol}_{B\times F} = \langle \mu, \beta\rangle_B \langle \nu,\phi\rangle_F f^{m-2l} \text{vol}_B \wedge \text{vol}_F$.
In particular, I am confused by the exponent of $f$: shouldn't it be just the straight Jacobian $f^m$?

Also, can any of you elaborate more about the use of the ON frame? My understanding is that, if I was to use, say for polar coordinates in 2d, $\theta^r = dr$ and $\theta^\phi = r d\phi$, then $\text{vol}{B\times F} = \theta^r \wedge \theta^\phi = r dr \wedge d\phi = \star{B\times F} 1$, which makes sense, but how does it change when I consider $\star_{B\times F}\omega^{(p)}$?
I don't see a general rule for a p-form with legs along just $B$, just $F$, or mixed legs.

Work out some $3+4$ dimensional examples just for fun so you have “room” to play around with the various legs (eg take a 2-form from one and a 3-form from the other and compute all three hodge duals (the two individual ones and the one of both wedged together)).

I can't tell if you're missing the main point or not. If $\omega_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$, is an oriented orthonormal coframe, then by definition for any multiindex $I$, $\star\omega_I = \pm\omega_J$, where $J$ is the complementary multiindex and the sign is $+$ when $I,J$ is an even permutation of ${1,\dots,n}$ and $-$ otherwise. You want it to be the case that $\omega_I\wedge\star\omega_I = \omega_1\wedge\dots\wedge \omega_n = \star 1$. You don't need to make a big deal about products and/or bundles if you just work with adapted orthonormal frames.

@TedShifrin, you were right, there's no need of proving anything. I used the ON covariant frame and it worked. Thanks everyone!
